# Who gained the largest amount of rep from old questions in August?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I was curious: who gained the largest amount of rep from old questions (older than 30 days) in August on StackOverflow?

It would also be interesting to exclude the rep gained from accepted answers (cause there was an accepted answer binge in August)

Answer (score 2):

Is there any kind of doubt? Jon Skeet!

Comment: He mentioned he got 300+ rep in a day *without answering a single question*.

Comment: That was a pretty special circumstance though: a flood of accepted answers due to a system change, basically.

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting on Marc.

Though its pretty hard to explicitly answer (since we do not have dates on votes) I can provide some stats:

Top 50 users, ordered by number of upvotes on old questions:

#### User             Reputation Votes OldVotes Accept OldAccept

```
Jon Skeet        92638      2185 444      241    43        
Marc Gravell     77239      1039 234      141    37        
cletus           50994      756  122      77     8         
JaredPar         53090      567  119      68     16        
S.Lott           52890      428  115      44     9         
Greg Hewgill     52579      522  115      45     10        
Joel Coehoorn    49926      442  114      43     10        
tvanfosson       61760      457  105      91     12        
Mehrdad          46795      935  98       90     13        
Konrad Rudolph   42831      353  92       24     4         
Bill the Lizard  41026      174  92       8      4         
Paolo Bergantino 36212      221  90       24     7         
Pax              46989      345  89       33     11        
Adam Davis       25880      88   87       0      0         
VonC             40301      266  80       50     5         
jalf             32502      380  78       30     4         
Alex Martelli    29639      1146 76       155    13        
litb             45168      273  74       24     4         
CMS              36510      551  62       71     1         
Michael Stum     23354      125  61       1      1         
Jeff Atwood      15029      71   59       0      0         
Tomalak          31463      165  59       32     6         
Norman Ramsey    22901      277  57       22     5         
Neil Butterworth 34628      968  56       45     8         
FlySwat          21351      71   56       3      2         
Shog9            21140      93   55       10     1         
Bill Karwin      30316      272  54       43     2         
bobince          19642      134  53       21     3         
Adam Rosenfield  34580      143  53       13     3         
Mitch Wheat      32316      213  52       26     9         
Brian R. Bondy   31931      135  51       7      0         
chaos            28425      584  50       65     3         
nickf            26180      261  50       27     3         
Matt Hamilton    22003      87   50       13     3         
Andrew Hare      34866      593  49       64     6         
splattne         17462      48   47       2      2         
James Curran     18438      47   46       4      4         
Vinko Vrsalovic  29848      239  45       20     5         
Lasse V. Karlsen 26695      242  45       14     2         
Craig Stuntz     15512      145  44       43     6         
John Saunders    24826      304  44       60     13        
Michael Burr     28081      231  42       13     2         
Nosredna         9469       91   42       5      1         
Jason Baker      21308      93   42       1      0         
Eric Lippert     6838       123  42       6      1         
Mark Cidade      15069      41   41       3      3         
Ian Boyd         4519       46   40       1      0         
marc_s           19098      506  40       122    11        
Brian            15726      113  39       14     2         
kronoz           8407       39   39       1      1
```

Looking at that lists, it is pretty clear that Jon is hitting the cap almost every day. However lots of Marc's old questions (a higher percentage than Jons) got accepted. Since both Jon and Marc both are hitting the cap daily, I would actually bet on Marc as being the person who gained most out of old questions, cause his ratios are better.

On an aside, if you order by OldAccept, you would get:

#### User             Reputation VotesOldVotes Accept OldAccept

```
Jon Skeet        92638      2185 444      241    43        
Marc Gravell     77239      1039 234      141    37        
Sam Saffron      11555      111  22       37     21        
JaredPar         53090      567  119      68     16        
Alex Martelli    29639      1146 76       155    13        
Mehrdad          46795      935  98       90     13        
John Saunders    24826      304  44       60     13        
tvanfosson       61760      457  105      91     12        
marc_s           19098      506  40       122    11        
Pax              46989      345  89       33     11        
Greg Hewgill     52579      522  115      45     10        
Joel Coehoorn    49926      442  114      43     10        
Reed Copsey      28050      722  29       92     9         
JP               16965      280  26       34     9         
Mitch Wheat      32316      213  52       26     9         
S.Lott           52890      428  115      44     9         
Neil Butterworth 34628      968  56       45     8         
Aiden Bell       8545       93   9        13     8         
cletus           50994      756  122      77     8         
darin            12896      59   11       14     7         
Paolo Bergantino 36212      221  90       24     7         
womp             14295      340  38       50     7         
eed3si9n         12190      32   13       9      7         
Tom Haigh        9228       96   13       20     6         
Grzenio          4505       52   9        9      6         
Greg             30586      282  30       40     6         
Tomalak          31463      165  59       32     6         
Andrew Hare      34866      593  49       64     6         
Uri              21017      59   22       7      6         
Craig Stuntz     15512      145  44       43     6         
joe              751        5    2        6      6         
ctacke           11933      21   7        11     6         
gbn              13651      185  12       49     6         
McWafflestix     11165      25   12       6      6         
Robert Gamble    12762      14   14       6      6         
Guffa            20566      377  30       50     6         
Mark Brackett    13839      92   30       23     6         
unwind           18952      83   21       11     6         
SpliFF           4659       26   21       6      5         
VonC             40301      266  80       50     5         
Michael Haren    10881      39   25       8      5         
Cheeso           8194       116  26       16     5         
Robert Munteanu  6670       72   16       16     5         
Quassnoi         28355      396  28       89     5         
Shay Erlichmen   4688       19   3        8      5         
Josh             15243      22   21       7      5         
Richard          9586       76   8        14     5         
Remus Rusanu     10682      223  12       50     5         
dirkgently       17291      18   18       5      5         
Vinko Vrsalovic  29848      239  45       20     5
```

Which makes me wonder, how did I manage to get to number 3 in any list :p

Sql:

```
drop table #t
go
select top 50 
    p.OwnerUserId as UserId,
    u.DisplayName as UserName,
    u.Reputation,
    SUM(case when VoteTypeId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Votes,
    SUM(case when p.CreationDate < (v.CreationDate - 30) and VoteTypeId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as OldVotes,
    SUM(case when VoteTypeId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Accept,
    SUM(case when p.CreationDate < (v.CreationDate - 30) and VoteTypeId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as OldAccept
into #t
from Votes v
join Posts p on p.Id = v.PostId
join Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerUserId
where p.CommunityOwnedDate is null 
    and OwnerUserId is not null 
    and DATEPART(m,v.CreationDate) = 8 
    and DATEPART(YEAR,v.CreationDate) = 2009
group by p.OwnerUserId, u.DisplayName, u.Reputation
order by OldAccept desc

go
exec spShog9
```

Answer (score 0):

As I found out with my question [over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20592/calculating-rep-earned-using-sandbox-or-data-dump), you can't determine rep gained from any particular posts because data on the change to CW and vote ordering (to take rep cap into account) is not available publicly.  So, there's no way to know, although if I were a betting man my money would be on Jon.

Comment: you can produce a rough estimate, that will be statistically somewhat correct.

Comment: @Sam: Your question is about a single data point, the one user who gained the most rep.  It's either right or wrong, statistics won't enter into it with just one data point.  In addition, for that particular question, I guarantee you the race will come down to who was able to beat the rep cap, so these particular limitations are especially problematic for that.