# Calculating rep earned using sandbox or data dump

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Is it possible to calculate the amount of reputation earned from particular posts via either the sandbox at [statoverflow.com/sandbox](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox) or from the data in the public [data dump](http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/)?  I can see we've got the posts and the votes table, but how do we take into account the daily reputation cap?

Does it involve emulating the entire rep calculation process?  Or is there an easier way?

Has anyone done this?

**EDIT:** I guess it's not possible.  If anyone can show otherwise, I've got a shiny acceptance checkmark that someone else gets instead of Kyle ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be possible to be exact, unfortunately, since it's possible to earn rep on a post that's later converted to wiki, and since the dump doesn't contain what time the votes were cast, it's impossible to know how many votes affected rep on the day that a post was converted to Wiki.

Comment: Darn.  That data must be available in the real DB, though, since recalculations are possible.

Comment: It is. It's just not provided in the extract.

Comment: @Kyle: Actually, I think that the times the votes were cast can be found in the `votes` table as `CreationDate`, and the time that the things became wiki is available in `posts` as `CommunityOwnedDate`... Am I wrong?

Comment: @Adam: I wasn't aware of `CommunityOwnedDate`, but admittedly my info is a few months old. Can you check `CreationDate` on the votes table and tell me if it has times, or just dates?

Comment: Just checked myself, it only has dates.

Comment: @Kyle: Bummer. :)